# Low memory warning when using AVCaptureStillImageOutput

Tags: iphone, memory-management, avcapturesession

I am observing memory burst of 25MB at `[self setImageData:[AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer]];`

The below code snippet is capturing the picture and providing jpg format of the data. When we take more pictures the system is reporting low memory warning.

In profiler we dont see leaks, but sometime the application reports low memory warning even at 20MB and application crashes.

```
[[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection 
                                        completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) 
 {
     [[self captureSession] stopRunning];
     if (imageSampleBuffer != NULL) 
     {
         CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment(imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
         if (exifAttachments) 
         {
             NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
         }


         [self setImageData:[AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer]];
     }
     imageSampleBuffer = nil;

     // call the designated delegate 
     [self.aCDMCameraCaptureNotificationDelegate imageDidSuccessfullyCaptured];
 }];
```

Comment: you will not be able to reduce the amount of memory this part of code uses unless you reduce the resolution of the picture you capture. You have to make your app ready to handle Low memory warnings without crashing.

Comment: After profiling, I see following memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Images, depending on their resolution, can occupy a bit of space in your memory. You need to make sure that the images you are producing don't hog everything up. There's a web image caching library called SDWebImage which can store your image in a key value store in memory and on disk so if the memory pressure increases too much it can flush the in memory image cache and when you need to restore the images you can call it from the disk.

If you're displaying images on screen, one image from the capture is fine but if you're displaying multiple images consider resizing the images down to their corresponding imageView sizes and storing both the original in cache.

Answer (score 0):

After profiling, I see following memory leaks.

```
#   Address Category    Event Type  RefCt   Timestamp   Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   0x2087cb80  __NSDate    Malloc  1   00:18.446.047   16  AVFoundation    -[AVCaptureSession _stopPreviewing]
1   0x2087cb80  __NSDate    Autorelease     00:18.446.056   0   AVFoundation    -[AVCaptureSession _stopPreviewing]
2   0x2087cb80  __NSDate    Release 0   00:28.472.781   0   Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool drain]
3   0x2087cb80  __NSDate    Free    0   00:28.472.787   -16 Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool drain]
4   0x2087cb80  Malloc 16 Bytes Malloc  1   00:42.834.501   16  libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_call_block_and_release
```

Can you point which statement is causing this memory leak?

Comment: Please execuse as the indentation after submit is poorly shown.